# spring_security_login not found

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-3

I am following the official [Spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-getting-started) for setting up security. However I receive a resource not found error for spring security login when it should load the default spring login jsp, right ?

here is my `web.xml` snippet:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>   
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and also the relevant section of `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http> 
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="user" password="mypassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I think I have all the relevant dependcies loaded (as well as the others such tx & core) I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: have you configured your web.xml?

Comment: yes, see the included relevant snippet

Comment: Were you able to access `/index` without the Spring Security configuration?

Comment: yes, it specifcally says spring_security_login not found

Comment: What's the servlet container/application server you are using?

Comment: Are you loading the file `applicationContext.xml` in your web.xml using the `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`? If you do please add the code.

Comment: Yeah it all works fine if I comment out the security sections. Well it navigates to the index page correctly without sending to login.jsp. However as soon as I uncomment the security it correctly intercepts but then fails to find spring-security-login

Comment: This is probably not related to the issue but I guess you want people to be sent to a login page for putting in their credentials? You should also add the `<form-login/>` tag in your Spring Security configuration. BTW: Does it work if you URL pattern for the security file is `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`?

Comment: I don't need to add that as I am trying to use the default spring setttings. Same error if I change the mapping from /index to /*

Comment: could you please post the full error you're getting ?

Comment: its 404 resource not found spring_security_login

Comment: What is the exact URL that is giving you a 404 (full URL please)?

Comment: //myhost/myapp/spring_security_login

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to map every URL in your app to be filtered through the Spring Security interceptor like so:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The interceptor will handle the login URL when it encounters it, and before it reaches any of your servlets or JSPs.

Comment: Thanks. That has fixed the issue, I don't understand why a filter mapping with wildcard works but "/index" does not. When "/index" is the url I am using ...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer that Pavel gave, it is the Spring Security filter chain that will process certain, specific, URLs such as `j_spring_security_check` and perform functions based on these particular URLs. Therefore, you will need to make sure, if you do not have a `url-pattern` of `/*` for your `<filter-mapping>`, that you at least explicitly include those particular URLs that are important to the Spring Security workflow that you are using. Depending on your authentication mechanism (username/password, OAuth, OpenID, etc.), these may or may not require you to dig into source code. Alternatively, you could experiment with a wildcard like `/j_*` or something. That should resolve your issue.

Comment: That has worked, thx. I don't understand why filter mapping of wildcard is required when I only want to filter one specific servlet/url

Comment: Because you also need to run the Spring Security-specific URLs such as login check through the Spring Sec filter chain. You shouldn't need a wildcard if you can identify all the specific URLs that need to go through Spring Security for this special server-side behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that you need a [DispatcherServlet](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/18-introduction-to-spring-mvc-web-framework-web-tier-1.html), because something (a servlet?) needs to return the login page in the response and I'm pretty sure its not a filter. I'll try to do exactly what you did and see what happens.

In the mean time you could start from the [sample application](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/sample-apps.html) bundled in the spring-security archive and strip it down to what you need. This always worked for me so far.

Comment: I am doing this in web.xml, what I posted is a snippet. It works fine without security settings - ie spring and the dispatcher servlet are hunky dory